# How to store the result of Google Dataproc query inside a variable GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a requirement wherein I need to count the number of records in a gcloud hive table and need to store this result inside a variable.

Below is the code for the same:

```
test=$(gcloud dataproc jobs submit hive --cluster=$CLUSTER --region=$REGION --execute="select count(*) from db.table;")
```

However, the above variable is not storing the count of records but is storing some logs which not useful for me.

Can please someone help me to find out how can we redirect the output of above query inside a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of gcloud command actually consists of two parts: stderr and standard output. The output that includes count number is actually insided the stderr. The following command can do this trick,

```
cnt_output=$((gcloud dataproc jobs submit hive --cluster=$CLUSTER --region=$REGION --execute "select count(*) from db.table;" 1>/dev/null) 2>&1)
```

This basically strips the standout first and then convert the stderr to standard output so that it can be saved into a variable, i.e. cnt_output

After that you can use the tool mentioned in the answer above to capture the number you want.

Comment: one command after got cnt_output that might be messy but works for me is: echo $cnt_output | awk -F'+------+' '{print $3;}' | awk -F' | ' '{print $3;}'

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the output you mention includes the logs for the Hive command *and* the output you want. It sounds like you just want the latter.

I'd recommend using something like `grep`, `sed`, or `Python` to capture the output. If you know regular expressions (regex), this should be pretty easy - [this is a good example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193223/regular-expression-to-extract-information-in-shell-script) of what you might want to do. If you have not used regex before, a regex builder [like this one](https://regexr.com/) will be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, the logs which are getting stored inside the variable does not contain the count value. Count value is printing on the screen itself.